# Splitting a thunderbolt connection

Tags: thunderbolt, gpu

I have a MacBook air and want to attach a external graphics card but it's already attached to a monitor, so the thunderbolt port is in use so does anyone know of a hub-like device to make my 1 thunderbolt port have 2 plugs. For clarification I want to take the 1 thunderbolt port in my Mac and add a hub (like 100$ or less) so I can instead have 2 thunderbolt ports. (If it's not clear, I want you to submit possible hubs I can buy (off Amazon if possible))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use an external GPU you need to have the connections in this order Mac > eGPU > Monitor. You should not use a thunderbolt hub, as support will become very limited (whether or not an eGPU can be run off of a hub), and performance will be greatly decreased (graphics need to go from Mac > hub > eGPU > hub > mac > hub > Monitor).